# Searching for object with jQ in command line

Tags: json, grep, jq

I have a JSON file of AWS security groups list. I am trying to fetch the Group Id using the Group Name. The object looks like the following:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [{
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "-1",
            }
        ],
        "Description": "launch-wizard-2 created 2017-10-21T09:19:40.007-04:00",
        "GroupName": "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80",
        "VpcId": "vpc-ceed12b7",
        "OwnerId": "712503525534",
        "GroupId": "sg-ee0c979c"
    }]
}
```

With jQ my attempt is as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.GroupId' ["GroupName": "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80"]
```

Error:
`jq: error: Could not open file [GroupName:: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file MY1SG-PUBLIC-80]: No such file or directory`

Comment: What does your full input look like? Your command doesn't quite make sense with what you're asking.

Comment: @JeffMercado I have updated partial input it replicates the full file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch the Group Id using the Group Name.

Assuming the input has been tweaked to make it valid JSON (*), the filter:

```
.SecurityGroups[] | select(.GroupName=="MY1SG-PUBLIC-80") | .GroupId
```

produces:

```
"sg-ee0c979c"
```

It might be worthwhile considering this alternative filter:

```
.[][]|select(.GroupName=="MY1SG-PUBLIC-80")|.GroupId
```

(*) The input as originally shown has an extraneous comma.

Comment: Wow! ```aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.[][] | select(.GroupName == "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80") | .GroupId' ``` It worked.

Answer (score 3):

Issue 1: Format
https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/ 
The second input to jq is the file you wish to read from. If this value is - the program will read from the instream.

Issue 2: Selection
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression) 
To select an element by value you should/could use a select statement
`select(.GroupName == "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80")`
`jq 'SCOPE | select(.GroupName == "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80") | .GroupId[]' -`
where SCOPE is the group you wish to look in. if SCOPE is `.[]`, it will scan every json entry. 
Following this, it pipes this group into a select filter, and trims it down to only ones that have GroupName set to the given value. 
This result set is then piped into a key filter, where it only returns the array of matching GroupID's.

Comment: ```aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.[][] | select(.GroupName == "MY1SG-PUBLIC-80") | .GroupId' - ``` I edited the GroupId[] to GroupId. Thanks!